# Differentiability of $f(x,y)=2xy+\frac{x}{y}$ at $(1,1)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to prove that the function $$f(x,y)=2xy+\frac{x}{y}
 $$ is differentiable at $(1,1)$.

So I got:    $$\nabla f(1,1)=\begin{bmatrix}3\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

and:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,1)}\frac{f(x,y)-\left(f(1,1)+\langle\nabla f(1,1),\binom{x-1}{y-1}\rangle\right)}{\|(x-1,y-1)\|}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,1)}\frac{2xy+\frac{x}{y}-3x-y+1}{\|(x-1,y-1)\|}$$

How can I show that  this limit is zero? I'm kind of stuck.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to solve the limit. It is sufficient to note that partial derivatives $f_x(x,y), f_y(x,y)$ are $\mathcal C^0$ in a neighborhood of $(1,1)$. Hence the function is differentiable in this point.

Answer (score 1):

why do you expect any trouble at $x = 1, y= 1?$  you have $f_x = 2y+\frac1y,\quad f_y = 2x - \frac x{y^2}.$  these evaluate to $\nabla f\big|_{x=1, y=1} = (3,1). $

---

$\bf p.s.$ let us look at how $f$ behaves near $x = 1, y = 1$ buy changing the variable $x = 1+h, y = 1+k.$  then 
$$\begin{align}f(1+h, 1+k) &= 2(1+h)(1+k)+2\frac{1+h}{1+k}\\&=2(1+h+k+hk)+2(1+h)(1+k)^{-1}\\
&=2(1+h+k+\cdots)+2(1+h)(1-k+\cdots)\\
&=2+2h+2k+\cdots+(2+h-k+\cdots)\\&=4+3h+k+\cdots\\
&=f(1,1)+(3,1)(h,k)^\top+\cdots \end{align} $$ 
the last equation shows that $$\nabla f\big|_{x=1, y=1} =(3,1). $$

Comment: i'm trying to prove differentiability by definition

Comment: @Amit, even then, it will be easier to look at $f(1+h, 1+k).$

Comment: can you explain please?

Comment: @Amit, see the p.s.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, but there is a nice way to prove the limit from the definition above that i gave? 2 vars limit?